# ggplot get a color for each value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, spatial

I have a spatial dataset, containing values from 0 to 10. I want every number (11 numbers) to have a unique color from a gradient. The simple plot function does the trick (assigning one color to one value) but my default is ggplot, which I also want to use here. ggplot only uses ten colors for some reason and I cannot figure out why. I think I might just be using the wrong scale_x_y function.

Reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
#Colors
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "red", "darkred", "black"))


# Create Raster
r <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
r[] <- sample(0:10, 10000, replace = T)

# Plot simple
plot(r, col=cols(11)) # 11 colors seen here



# Convert to df
r <- as.data.frame(r, xy=T)


# Plot with ggplot
X <- ggplot(data = r) + geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer), interpolate = F) + 
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors=cols(11), breaks=seq(0,10,1), show.limits=T)
print(X) # only 10 colors seen here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `scale_fill_stepsn` the breaks are at the limits of each bin. If you have a sequence of 11 breaks, then you only have ten bins (if you have 11 fence posts you only have 10 stretches of fence between them). You need to add one to your sequence of breaks, otherwise the level 10 will be excluded:

```r
ggplot(data = r) + 
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer), interpolate = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors = cols(11), breaks = seq(0, 11, 1), 
                    show.limits = TRUE) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

An alternative is to use a manual scale, which I think makes more sense here. As I understand it, you are treating the fill color as a discrete variable, and the labels should correspond to the levels rather than corresponding to the break *between* labels as implied by `scale_fill_stepsn`

```r
ggplot(data = r) + 
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = factor(layer, 10:0))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(cols(11)), name = 'layer') +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To get the legend at the bottom, try:

```r
ggplot(data = r) + 
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = factor(layer, 0:10))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols(11), name = 'layer    ') +
  coord_equal() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = 'top', nrow = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        legend.title = element_text(hjust = 3, vjust = 0.25))
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, it fixes the initial problem, thank you so much! However, it creates another. I have my legend below the graph horizontally (title left, numbers ascending left to right from 0:10). With this option 2-3 colors are stacked above each other (below the graph). Do you know how to add this too?

Comment: @Ferdi Did you try adding `+ theme(legend.position = 'bottom')` to your plot?

Comment: yes, it seems that ggplot just puts the vertical legend below the legend and splitting it because there isn't enough space. But I want to basically have the whole thing rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! In the guide I just changed label.position to "bottom" and the vjust in legend.title to 0.8 :)